# During restore, how does sql server know the point until where the tlog record is applied to the data page?

Tags: sql-server, restore, transaction-log

During restore, when the tlog records are applied to the data page, redo, undo phase, how does sql server know which transactions are already present in the data page and which transaction to start applying to the data page?

Answer (score 0):

In short, each backup stores a series of **Log Sequence Numbers (LSNs)** which represent the backup chain and guide the restore to properly apply the correct transactions. The LSNs are sequential, and therefore the restore process applies the backups in order of their LSNs. Additionally, one of the types of LSNs is called the `DatabaseBackupLSN` which identifies the nearest full backup that starts this chain of backups.

You can find in depth information on how it all works in [Understanding SQL Server Log Sequence Numbers for Backups](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3209/understanding-sql-server-log-sequence-numbers-for-backups/):

> When restoring a database, the initial database RESTORE sequence must begin from a FULL database backup. A database RESTORE sequence cannot begin with a differential file backup or transaction log backup. When restoring databases there are four important LSNs: FirstLSN, LastLSN, CheckpointLSN and DatabaseBackupLSN.

> Some attributes of a differential database backup LSNs are: The DatabaseBackupLSN value for the differential backup identifies the full database backup that is required in order to apply the differential database backup.

> The DatabaseBackupLSN value for the differential backup will match its base full database backup CheckpointLSN.

> The CheckpointLSN maps to the CheckpointLSN of the first transaction log backup after the differential backup.

> Some attributes of a transaction log backup LSNs are: A LSN uniquely identifies every record in a transaction log backup.

> The FirstLSN and CheckpointLSN of the first transaction log backup is also the first full database backup CheckpointLSN if the backup is taken when the database is idle and no replication is configured.

> The transaction log LSN chain is not affected by a full or differential database backup.

> LSN are sequential in nature. A higher LSN value indicates a later point in time.